# Custom Wordpress Does Not Display Anything But Background in IE

Tags: themes

I have a custom, well kinda custom wordpress in only one page of my site, the background only displays in Internet explorer, no body or content just background though in firefox it's fine as with other browsers. Reverted back to the original twenty ten and it shows in IE. I know the code is horrible but it was a shot at making a custom theme and it worked fine before. If I thought I could fix it myself I wouldn't ask the pros here. You guys have helped me a ton !!

Also, if you view the source, it shows content being there.

http://www.shakedownnationals.com/news/

Sincerely Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initial style declaration that sets the background color:

```
background:#000D37;
```

You have an open HTML comment but no close.  Close that and you should be fine.

Comment: Dear hereswhatidid, Thanks a million !!! that was it, I cannot believe it was that simple, working like a charm for a half cooked WP hacked html site. Such a small error I just couldn't see after hours of updating and re doing this from its original website. If there was a way to buy you a beer I would !!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Just mark the answer as correct and we'll call it even, ok?

Comment: For Sure, please tell me where this is, I'm not seeing it

Comment: Should be a checkmark below the up/down arrows next to my answer.

Comment: Done, and thank you, I will be looking for more of your help, I'm ecstatic, you know how it gets looking at code all the time, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your html code errors; that will fix many display problems in IE as well as other browsers. See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  shakedownnationals.com news  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//shakedownnationals.com/news/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. And then fix your CSS errors: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fshakedownnationals.com%2Fnews%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: songdogtech, thank you for your reply, I do understand that the code is pretty bad for errors, this site was done hastily and never really got it right. I will look more into getting all pages sorted out and fixed, you're right code is better when valid. "Hereswhatidid's" answer fixed it. Just one stupid <!-- caused it all without the close.